Calculate 95 confidence intervals with predict() function for glmer model?
is it possible to some how get or calculate 95 confidence intervals with predict() function for glmer model?
Example for Iris dataset
pois.glmer.Ran.iris <- glmer(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length + (1| Species), data = iris, family = poisson)
#create newdata to test
newdata = data.frame(Sepal.Length = 10, Species = 'virginica')
#use model to predict value using new data
predict(pois.glmer.Ran, newdata, type="response", re.form=NULL, allow.new.levels = TRUE, interval = "prediction", level = 0.95)

Interval and level doesn't seem to work anymore for the predict function but I need to estimate the 95% CI?

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147836/prediction-interval-for-lmer-mixed-effects-model-in-r
